# Conditionally filling missing data in R

Tags: r, paste, missing-data

I have a data frame such that:

```
df$v1 = c('2', '', '', '', '3', '', '4', '', '', 'OT')
```

I would like to format this variable as an ordinal variable. However,

```
df$v1 = as.ordered(df$v1)
```

Results in:

```
Ord.factor w/ 5 levels ""<"2"<"3"<"4"<..: 2 1 1 1 3 1 4 1 1 5
```

R reads the empty cells as unique entries and places them first in ordering. What I would like to do, is fill the empty cells with the value of the last cell above it (or to its left depending on your orientation) to have a value. In other words, this vector should actually look like:

```
df$v1 = c('2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', 'OT')
```

I believe this change will allow me to format the variable as ordinal as desired. I've tried every combination of as.ordered(), as.factor(), levels = c('1', '2', '3', '4', 'OT'), and ordered = TRUE. However, R does not use the "levels" or "ordered" arguments when included; the as.factor() function, without the use of the "levels" or "ordered" arguments, does not result in an ordinal variable; and, the as.ordered() function resuts n the problem described above. Therefore, I believe filling the empty cells before conversion is the best solution. What's the best way to do this? I know I could use:

```
df$v1 = as.ordered(sub('^$', '2', df$v1))
```

to fill the empty cells with "2"s; but, the replacement value differs for each cell. I could do something like:

```
df.a = df[1:4, ]
df.b = df[5:6, ]
df.c = df[7:9, ]
df.d = df[10, ]
df.a$v1 = as.ordered(sub('^$', '2', df.a$v1))
df.b$v1 = as.ordered(sub('^$', '3', df.b$v1))
df.c$v1 = as.ordered(sub('^$', '4', df.c$v1))
```

However, I'm looking for a way to do it automatically. While the above 7 lines would produce the resuts I desire in this case, I have a number of other tables suffering from the same formatting problem; and, the number of rows that correspond to each necessary partition are different for each one. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `na.locf` from `zoo` to replace the NA elements with the non-NA previous adjacent element after converting the blanks (`""`) to NA

```
library(zoo)
df$v1 <- with(df, na.locf(replace(v1, v1=="", NA)))
df$v1
#[1] "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "3"  "3"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "OT"
```

---

This can also be done with `base R` by creating a grouping variable and then filling it with `ave`

```
with(df,  ave(v1, cumsum(v1!=""), FUN = function(x) x[1]))
#[1] "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "3"  "3"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "OT"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `fill` from the `tidyr` package?

```
library(tidyr)

df$v1 <- ifelse(df$v1 == '', NA, df$v1) # requires NA not empty string
df <- df %>% fill(v1)
```